# How is Russell’s Paradox equal to the universal set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How is Russell’s Paradox, which is defined as the collection
$$
\{ x \mid x \notin x \},
$$
equal to the universal set $ \{ x \mid x = x \} $? Do we assume that if $ x = x $, then $ x \notin x $? My question is specifically what is written at the end of Page 21 of [this document](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem confused about the relationship between Russell's Paradox and the non-existence of the so-called universal set. I will try to clarify without referring to the notion of a class.

If you assume the existence of a universal set $U$ such that $\forall x:x\in U$ and your set theory allows for arbitrary subsets and does *not* disallow $x\in x$, then you can define set $R$ such that $\forall x:[x\in R\iff x\in U \land x\notin x]$. Note the similarities to the standard presentation of Russell's Paradox.

Applying the definition of $R$ to itself, we have $R\in R \iff R\in U \land R\notin R$. Since, by definition, we must have $R\in U$, this is a contradiction. Thus, the existence of $U$, as defined above, results in a contradiction. Thus, $U$ cannot exist.

Thus, the non-existence of the universal set can be proven (in the set theories described here) by using the same kind of contradiction that arises in Russell's Paradox

Comment: Thanks Dan. I was actually asking for how they get this equality, the one that I mention in my question in these notes. Its on page 21 of the notes

http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf

Comment: @AbdulRahman I can see why you might have been confused.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few problems with your statements.

1. If there is no universal set, then $\{x\mid x=x\}$ is not a set. This is because this collection is the collection of *all* sets, since every set is equals to itself.

   In some set theories like $\sf NF$ there is a universal set, but in others like $\sf ZFC$ there is none.
2. $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ need not be equal to the entire class of sets. It is possible to arrange a situation where we have $x\in x$, but still $x=x$. In some set theories this is outright provable, for example in $\sf NF$ where you have a universal set $U$ then we necessarily have $U\in U$. In such situation, as I wrote, the two classes are not equal.
3. Russell's paradox is not that $\{x\mid x\notin x\}=\{x\mid x=x\}$. It is a paradox that shows that the class $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ is not a set. It begins by assuming otherwise, then it is a set $A$. If $A\in A$, then by definition $A\notin A$; and if $A\notin A$ then by definition $A\in A$. So we have a contradiction, therefore $A$ is not a set.

Comment: Thanks Asaf. I was actually asking for how they get this equality, the one that I mention in my question in these notes. Its on page 21 of the notes math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf

Comment: Are you sure the link is correct? It doesn't really respond very well. My guess is that they assume $\sf ZF$ or some extension thereof. The axiom of regularity (also known as the axiom of foundation sometimes) allows us to prove that $\forall x(x\notin x)$. Therefore the two classes are equal. Neither is a set, though.

Comment: www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf

Comment: The file says the following thing, "Upon reflection, you might say that in fact, nothing is an element of itself". This reflection is informal, and later on when you are introduced to the axiom of foundation (p. 23), this reflection becomes formal.

Comment: In the future I suggest including this information in your question.

Comment: Thanks Asaf, editted my question to include the link now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila As I suggested above, even if your set theory doesn't disallow $x\in x$ you can prove that the set of all things does not exist.

Comment: @Dan: Tell that to Quine, and to all the people who are working on consistency proofs for $\sf NF$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you explain briefly?

Comment: @Dan: In the Quine's set theory, $\sf NF$ (New Foundations) there is a universal set. The question whether or not it is consistent relative to $\sf ZF$ is open, although the door is being closed at these days (one recent preprint on arXiv, and another mathematician working on the problem for a while with rudimentary preprint available). If you can prove that no set theory can have a universal set, then you effectively prove that $\sf NF$ is inconsistent. But thinking about it, you do even more. You prove that $\sf NFU$ is inconsistent, therefore $\sf PA$ and $\sf ZFC$ are too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you want to have a universal set, it might work if you disallow arbitrary subsets or $x\in x$. Seems so unnecessary.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, the idea of Quine was to disallow arbitrary (even bounded) comprehension. So in a sense his set theory is much closer to type theory than to naive set theory. It is still a theory which has a universal set, and it is still something being researched by very respected people, even if it is an oddity to most people.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Intuitively, it seems to me that the fewer elements you have in your set theory, the more likely your system is consistent. Assuming *a priori* a set containing everything just seems to be asking for trouble. I favour a set theory that doesn't assume *a priori* that any objects or sets exist -- where the existence of anything is provisional or hypothetical.

Comment: @Dan: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not surprised.

Comment: @Dan: Is this because you often say things which have little context to previous statement?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Something like that.